# Upgrade from Ubuntu 12.10 to 13.10 - effect on boot

Tags: dual-boot, upgrade, 13.10

I have a triple boot system: Ubuntu 12.10, Windows 7 & windows XP.

When installing Ubuntu 12.10, following various on-line guides, I created a separate boot partition for Ubuntu so that the Windows boot files in the MBR would not be overwritten. This worked perfectly, and everything has been running smoothly.

My question is, if I upgrade to Ubuntu 13.10 by selecting the 'upgrade' option from the 'Installation Type' menu, will the installation seamlessly retain the existing Ubuntu boot partition, or will it revert to the default MBR?

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes , upgrading the Ubuntu affects the MBR.  It is not a problem since you can easily repair the GRUB through the command-line.  Refer this link : [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)